# Why count the Omer?

Tags: sefirat-ha-omer, shavuos

The Torah enjoins us to count the Omer for agricultural reasons [[Leviticus 23:15-17]](https://www.sefaria.org/Leviticus.23.15-17?ven=The_Contemporary_Torah,_Jewish_Publication_Society,_2006&vhe=Miqra_according_to_the_Masorah&lang=bi&aliyot=0).  Later, the counting was reinterpreted as eager anticipation for the giving of the Torah on Shavuot.

(1) What is the earliest written source of this reinterpretation?

(2) Did the Israelites know the Torah was going to be given at a specific date, so they could count in anticipation?  If so, what is the source?

Comment: What agricultural reasons?

Comment: If Moshe Rabbeinu added a day on his own, how could they of known that 7 weeks prior?

Comment: @Heshy -- https://www.sefaria.org/Leviticus.23.15-17?ven=The_Contemporary_Torah,_Jewish_Publication_Society,_2006&vhe=Miqra_according_to_the_Masorah&lang=bi&aliyot=0

Comment: No reason, that I can see, is given in the verse for counting.

Comment: @DoubleAA -- The injunction is only associated with agriculture.  At any rate, my 2 questions stand.

Comment: @MauriceMizrahi ...except for the usage of "reinterpretation". Anyway it's not only associated with agriculture but with the holiday[s]

Comment: Nothing in the verses implies the reason is agricultural. -1

Answer (score 2):

The direct answer would be a Midrash quoted by the [Ran](https://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=37955&st=&pgnum=414) at the end of Pesachim

> ובהגדה אמרו: בשעה שאמר להם משה "תעבדון את אלקים על ההר הזה", אמרו לו ישראל: "משה רבינו! אימתי עבודה זו? אמר להם: "לסוף חמישים יום." והיו מונין כל אחד ואחד לעצמו, מכאן קבעו חכמים לספירת העומר. כלומר: בזמן הזה שאין אנו מביאין קרבן ולא עומר, אלא מחשבין חמישים יום לשמחת התורה כמו שמנו ישראל באותו זמן. וזהו דרך דרש, דעיקרא דמילתא הוא שזהו זכר למקדש.

The [Aruch Hashulchan 489:3](https://www.sefaria.org/texts/Halakhah) explains that the pesukim mention the agriculture aspect to teach us about counting for the Torah

> יש לומר דעיקר הספירה הוא למתן תורה, כמו שמנו ישראל מקודם לפי המדרש שהבאנו. אך הקדוש ברוך הוא צוה להביא קרבנות בתחילת המניין מעומר שעורים, ובסופו מחטים, להורות דבלתי התורה אנחנו כבהמות נדמה שמאכלן שעורים. כמו שאמרו בסוטה (טו ב) שקרבן סוטה הוא מן השעורים: היא עשתה מעשי בהמה – לפיכך קרבנה מאכל בהמה, עיין שם. וכשקבלו התורה הוי דמות אדם להנה, ולכן קרבנם מן החטים מאכל אדם, ולכן צותה התורה למנות להקרבן. אבל עיקר הכוונה הוא למתן תורה, ולכן המצוה גם בזמן הזה (כן נראה לעניות דעתי).